# Let $z=\ln \tan\frac xy.$ What is $z_x$ and what is $z_y$?

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, special-functions

Let $$z=\ln \tan\frac xy.$$ What is $z_x$ and what is $z_y$?

Thanks ahead:)

What I have tried:

$$z_x=\frac{1}{\tan \frac xy} \frac{1}{1+(\frac xy)^2} \frac 1y=\frac {y}{\tan \frac xy (x^2+y^2)}$$

$$z_y=\frac {-x}{\tan \frac xy (x^2+y^2)}.$$

I am not sure I am right. Help, help, help...

Comment: To find the partial derivative, proceed as usual and pretend that the other variable is constant. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: Can you differentiate $\ln(\tan(x/4))$?  If so, you should not have any trouble finding $z_x$ in your problem.

Comment: @David: I'm not sure I am right. So,,,I post this question. Seeking help.

Comment: @Paul Then do you have at least some attempt in the problem? If you post your work, people can critique or improve it.

Comment: As @T.Bongers said, please post your work (edit it into your question).  You **cannot** learn mathematics by looking up answers in the back of the book (or online equivalent).

Comment: @T. Bongers,Please see the edited vision...

Comment: Your working suggests that you think the derivative of $\tan\theta$ is $1/(1+\theta^2)$.  This is the first thing you need to fix.

Comment: We're not using $tan^{-1}\frac{x}{y}$. You need to find the derivative of $tan \frac{x}{y}$ with respect to x first and then to y. Rewrite it as $tan xy^{-1}$ to make it easier. Then find the partial derivative in terms of x.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, you misread $\tan$ as $\tan^{-1}$.

The answers are:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
z_x = \frac{1}{\tan\frac{x}{y}}\frac{1}{y}\sec^2\frac{x}{y}=\frac{\sec\frac{x}{y}\csc\frac{x}{y}}{y} \\
z_y = -\frac{1}{\tan\frac{x}{y}}\frac{x}{y^2}\sec^2\frac{x}{y}=\frac{-x \sec\frac{x}{y}\csc\frac{x}{y}}{y^2}
\end{array}
$$